# How to allow default user to log in to Microsoft Windows 10 without a password

Tags: windows-10, password-management

I have a remote data logging computer (Windows 10) that will restart after a power failure. Previously, I was able to allow the default user account to log back in after such a failure without a password. This is handy as there is no one on site. To set this up, I opened netplwiz from a terminal and unchecked the box next to "user must enter a username and password". This is gone after a recent Win10 update. How can I make it so the user does not have to enter a username and password for the system to open that account?

Comment: Are the applications that run on this computer dependent on an active user session? As in, while this has worked in the past there are good reasons why it is removed as an option now, and it may be better, in the long term, to go back a few steps and see if there are better, more reliable and secure ways, to log this data that doesn't break these security conventions.

Comment: “user must enter a username and password” - Absolutely still exists in the build for Windows 10 22H2 and Windows 11 23H2. I would want to know, at a minimum, which update you suspect.

Comment: I don't actually need to know which update to rule out the fact the update is the reason.  [This](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/users-must-enter-a-username-and-password-to-use-this-computer-missing) article is much older than the last 30 days and describes exactly what you describe.  At some point, you or an administrator configured Windows Hello to be the only acceptable authentication method.

Comment: All services are configured with a login account. Com servers RunAs. Applications under LocalMachine\..\run, run with machine login. Many of the default accounts do not have a default printer configured, but apart from that, do you need to log in for data logging?

Answer (score 0):

The following is crude and, above all else insecure, but will work for this isolated system. It allows the default user to be logged into Windows 10 on reboot without a password.

```
1.) Press Win + R to open the Run dialog. Type regedit and press Enter to open the Registry Editor.
2.) Navigate to the following registry key: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon
3.) In the right pane, look for a value named DefaultUserName. If it doesn't exist, create it: Right-click on an empty space in the right pane. Choose New String Value. Name it "DefaultUserName". Set the DefaultUserName value data to the username of the account to log in automatically.
4.) Similarly, create a new String Value named DefaultPassword and set its value data to the password of the specified user account.
5.) Create a DefaultDomainName value and set its value data to the computer's name.
6.) Create a value named AutoAdminLogon. Set it's value field to "1".
7.) Restart the computer.
```